# Benchmarking for DISK I/O Writes Per Second - ElasticSearch and MySQL

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, load, performance-testing, disk-io

During working on our project we needed to decide should we use "ElasticSearch" or "MySQL" to record the audit/trail logs of the system. Searching speed is not an issue here, we needed to see the disk I/O performance for both platforms. I had no experience of disk i/o monitoring, so after a little research I decided to monitor the writes per second for both ElasticSearch and MySQL via a simple load running script.

Should I consider writes per second for disk i/o performance ? Am I going in to the right direction ? Also, I'm not sure if less no. of writes per second is better or worst ?

Comment: i think that depends on what exactly you want to measure. Where do you get your data from, what system are we talking about.

Comment: @FloWin it could be anything, the important thing is the frequency of the data (logs) we are receiving, there could be around thousands of records per day. We just need to save the hard disk for frequent data writing.

Comment: So you want to store data logs in a database, right? And you want to measure your disk performance to see which database would suit your needs better? The more writes/s the better is the disk (if your try to only write).

Comment: You shouldn't be measuring Disk I/O you should be measuring documents stored per time period.  Unless you are trying to see which platform uses less IO for a given volume.  But your question is not clear in this regard.  If you are trying to see which has the lower IO requirements, primarily you would be looking at write IO but read is also a factor.  Write IO is usually the determining factor though.

Comment: @AaronM Yes, I'm trying to see which has the lower IO requirements. As I mentioned, the frequency is quite high that is why we want our DB (no SQL or SQL ) to avoid frequent writes on the hard disk.